# session lost while redirecting the jsp page using Java servlet filter

Tags: java, session, servlets, servlet-filters

While using response.sendredirect session lost the value in https protocol, how to resolve this issue in java

Answer (score 0):

Your recent edit does not help more than original post

Not only one case would cause this problem, one possible would be session tracking issue, if it's cookie(by default) check the cookies once you login.

Another one would be because of path session cookie configs, check for cookie path, domain attributes.

Also note in filter or generally anywhere you either redirect or forward a request you cannot do anything with the request and you must consider the request done, best practice would be `return` the method just after the redirect or forward.